# Is XMP metadata future safe?

Tags: metadata, xmp

I've been thinking about creating a FOSS photo diary application and am considering storing notes that the user makes in XMP metadata inside the file

It's important that this information is kept as it can be of high value for the user. **Do you know if storing metadata in XMP is future safe?** For how long time can this standard be expected to remain so that the user is able to read the metadata?

I'm thinking of using jpg as well as png files in the application

Grateful for help with this!

Comment: Future safe, yes.  XMP is human readable so at the worst people can open the file in a text editor.  Safe from other poorly written open source junk... probably not.  In the short description of what you plan to write I (as an experienced developer) see huge problems ahead for you.  I suggest you write your code for you, and don't worry about 'users' at least until you have something worth showing them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only God really *knows* that... ;-)

Actually [Extensible Metadata Platform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) was introduced in 2001 (16 years ago) and today it can be located in several file types and is supported by tens of freeware or proprietary programs.

That makes it very likely to be readable in the future - probably longer than your application could be executed (the build for current platforms) or even compiled (programming language standards change).

Another point: XMP is an XML document and can be also stored in a [sidecar file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidecar_file). Thousands of programs use XML format so the XMP will be very likely parseable in the future.

Hope this helps.